# Text box with default text

Tags: javascript

I have a text box with a default text. I am using javascript to dissapear it when the user clicks in this, but i want to make it work without javascript. Is there any way to do that in html or php? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in flat HTML5 using the `placeholder` attribute of the `<input>` tag

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Default Text" />
```

Comment: I am using XHTML 1.0 Transitional, it works fine but it not compliant. Unfortunatelly I can't use it. Thank you! If you have any other idea please post it. Thank You once again!

Comment: Just change your doctype string to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and you'll be fine

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't do that as I am working on a project and the specifications say that i have to use XHTML 1.0 Transitional. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5, there has been the introduction of new attribute called `placeholder`

You can use it like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="text to show and hide" />
```

Answer (score 0):

it is simple you can use html5 control also.there
like.

```
<input  type="text" name="txtFirstName" id="txtFirstName"
placeholder="enter first name" />
```